# Why didn't Remington Rand integrate their own teleprinter in their UNIVAC?

Tags: teletype, univac

Remington was a successful typewriter producer whose shift-key products had been the role model of typewriter. Remington Rand was an early manufacturer of Computers and created the famous UNIVAC series.

While Remington did modify [a Remington Standard electric typewriter](https://americanhistory.si.edu/collections/search/object/nmah_850058) into a metal magnetic tape writer as an input device called [UNITYPER](https://oztypewriter.blogspot.com/2014/02/the-remington-rand-unityper-1955-60.html) for [UNIVAC I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIVAC_I), UNITYPER was an offline device whose output was to be read by a tape reader naming [UNISERVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNISERVO) thus can't be defined as a typewriter (ASR/KSR/RO) or a reperforator; and later in [UNIVAC 1050](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIVAC_1050) the peripheral to communicate and control was an ASR-33 from **Teletype Corporation**.

Searching [THE SCIENCE MUSEUM GROUP](https://collection.sciencemuseumgroup.org.uk/search?q=remington&page%5Bsize%5D=50&page%5Btype%5D=search&page%5Bsort%5D=default&page%5Bnumber%5D=1), it was found that Remington made razors, typewriters and even [electric calculators](https://collection.sciencemuseumgroup.org.uk/objects/co8087987/remington-rand-edc-iii-desktop-calculator-with-20-digit-precision-and-a-fixed-decimal-point-desktop-calculator), without any result of teletype/teleprinter. As a comparison, another famous typewriter maker Olivetti manufactured teleprinters from 1938 to 1991, and electric computers from 1948.

If there was any Remington teleprinter, why didn't Remington Rand integrate their own teleprinter in their UNIVAC? If not, why didn't Remington Rand make their own teleprinters and what made so?

Comment: It's claimed the typewriter in the photo was a [Remington teleprinter](https://mildenhall.moadoph.gov.au/photo/7370) sometime between January 1921 to December 1935, but I really can't tell.

[image: Remington teleprinter]

Comment: You are asking why company X never thought to do Y when, _in hindsight,_ Y seems like a good idea. Such questions often are not possible to answer.

Comment: P.S., The "UNIVAC 1050" article that you cite doesn't prove that RR ever resold Teletype machines. It only shows that the U.S. Navy bought a Teletype and attached it to a UNIVAC computer.